# Erro na syntax e não sei onde

Tags: mysql

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Eu to querendo criar uma trigger desconto para caso o usuário selecione a forma de pagamento 6 que é boleto ele tenha 15% de desconto no valor q será pago, então o ValorPagar q é onde fica o valor que a pessoa vai pegar é pra receber o valor com desconto

```
CREATE TRIGGER Desconto BEFORE INSERT
ON Pagamento
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF NEW.CodigoFormaPagamento = 6 THEN
        SET NEW.ValorPagar = (NEW.ValorPagar * 0.15);
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: botei a imagem para ver onde ta acontecendo o erro

Comment: Obg por colocar o código, assim fica fácil de copiar.

Comment: que estranho, aqui ta assim

Comment: tirei, agora ele nao ta acusando erro no ultimo END mas ta acusando os outros dois onde já estvao

Comment: usando o que você me passou deu certo, mas poderia me explicar por favor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por padrão o MySQL entende o `;` como um delimitador de instrução, então você deve definir um delimitador temporário diferente de `;`, senão ele não conseguirá saber onde terminam os procedimentos e as instruções no código.

```
DELIMITER $$ /* $$ como delimitador temporário  */
CREATE TRIGGER Desconto BEFORE INSERT
ON Pagamento
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.CodigoFormaPagamento = 6 THEN
        SET NEW.ValorPagar = (NEW.ValorPagar * 0.15);
    END IF
END $$
DELIMITER ; /* restaura o delimitador original  */
```

**[Fonte na página da documentação oficial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html)**